# mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) não funciona

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou trabalhando com Linux agora e instalei separadamente o Apache, PHP e Mysql, porém em testes com alguns sistemas, observei que o mysqli_affected_rows() não funciona. O teste foi baseado em cima desse código:

```
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);    

    $conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','111488','bd_construcao');

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"Email",FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO tb_cadastros VALUES(null,'".$ip."','".$email."',NOW());");

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0)){
            $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
      }else{
            $_SESSION["Erro"] = time() + 3;
            $_SESSION["Mensagem"] = "Erro...";
     }
```

Nenhum erro é mostrado, os dados não são inseridos e a página fica em branco. Porém quando eu tiro a linha:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0)){
            $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
      }else{
            $_SESSION["Erro"] = time() + 3;
            $_SESSION["Mensagem"] = "Erro...";
}
```

O cadastro é efetuado.

Comment: Esta linha que tirou seria o `if` inteiro? E se der um `var_dump` no retorno da função, o que aparece?

Comment: Olá Anderson. Sim, seria o if inteiro. Não entendi sobre dar o var_dump no retorno da função. Dar em que exatamente?

Comment: Existe um `)` a mais no `if`. Em `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0)){` seria `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0){`, de `)){` para `){`

Comment: Olá Inkeliz. Perfeito. Realmente foi uma falha minha. Obrigado pela observação.